# How to release correctly memory in iOS: Memory is never released; potential leak of memory pointed to by

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have the next code developed for converting an NSMutableString object into NSData object:

```
-(NSData *)desSerializarFirma:(NSMutableString *)firma{

    NSArray *arregloBits    = [firma componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    unsigned c              = arregloBits.count;
    uint8_t *bytes          = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < c; i ++)
    {
        NSString *str = [arregloBits objectAtIndex:i];
        int byte = [str intValue];
        bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
    }

    return [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];
}
```

when I analyze this with xCode it says

```
memory is never released; potential leak of memory pointed to by 'bytes'
```

this statement points to the last line of my code:

```
return [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];
```

if I release the object by executing 'free(bytes)' then I get my function useless... any help I'll appreciate

Comment: You just need to free it when you're done with it.

Comment: you're right, with your answer and the help of dasblinkenlight I could resolve it thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to `free` the bytes, because `NSData` does not take ownership of it: it cannot know if the array is a temporary or a dynamic, so it makes a copy of it.

To fix this problem, replace

```
return [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];
```

with

```
NSData *res = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];
free(bytes);
return res;
```

Comment: Hey it worked!!! thanks for the answer, I developed that function in that way because all I wanted was to reduce the code to its minimal expression possible, well it shows that less code is not always the best, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
return [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:c];
```

with

```
return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:bytes length:c];
```

then `NSData` takes ownership if the bytes and will free them for you.