# Potential leak of an object stored into

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm analyzing this block of code from an SDK and basing the kind of error on the answer of my latest question:

[How to release correctly memory in iOS: Memory is never released; potential leak of memory pointed to by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087510/how-to-release-correctly-memory-in-ios-memory-is-never-released-potential-leak)

dasblinkenlight suggested me to create an NSData object for could releasing my uint8_t *bytes...

But here in this code:

```
/**
 * this will set the brush texture for this view
 * by generating a default UIImage. the image is a
 * 20px radius circle with a feathered edge
 */
-(void) createDefaultBrushTexture{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(64, 64));
    CGContextRef defBrushTextureContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(defBrushTextureContext);

    size_t num_locations = 3;
    CGFloat locations[3] = { 0.0, 0.8, 1.0 };
    CGFloat components[12] = { 1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0,
        1.0,1.0,1.0, 1.0,
        1.0,1.0,1.0, 0.0 };
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint myCentrePoint = CGPointMake(32, 32);
    float myRadius = 20;

    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), myGradient, myCentrePoint,
                                 0, myCentrePoint, myRadius,
                                 kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    UIGraphicsPopContext();

    [self setBrushTexture:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

I got the same kind of error on these lines:

potential leak of an object stored into 'myColorspace'

```
CGGradientRef myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components, locations, num_locations);
```

potential leak of an object stored into 'myGradient'

```
UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

I tried with:

```
free(myColorspace);
free(myGradient);
```

but I keep the same kind of issues, what can I do to resolve it

thanks in advance all your support

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Listen to exactly what the errors are telling you.

"potential leak of an object stored into `myColorspace`"

Lets look at colorspace and see if we can find the problem. `myColorspace` is created `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB` so retain count is +1, but then never released. This is unbalanced and it needs to be released at the end. We need to add a `CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorSpace);`

"potential leak of an object stored into `myGradient`"

Same problem, creation with retain count +1, with no corresponding release. Add a `CGGradientRelease(myGradient);`

Do not use `free` on anything created with a framework `Create` function. The internal structure could be more complex, and free will not properly take care of all the memory. Use a corresponding `Release` function.

Comment: Just want to add that any Apple functions with "Create" or "Copy" in the name return a +1 object.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i

Comment: @jsd agreed, important info.