# CGGradientRef - potential leak of an object

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I am getting 'Potential leak of an object' warning from an analyser upon the following code:
[image]

Shall I release something in `-(void)dealloc;`? How?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18088361/988169

Comment: Please post your code as text, rather than as screenshots.

Comment: Code neither includes analyser warnings (in blue), nor context arrows. This is why i am posting screenshot.